# How to add the another component in angular and it has the same data as previous component and with some extra information on it

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an angular application and I have created the login and dashboard page using angular.And also I have completed the navigation between the login and user dashboard and also called the API which shows the data in dashboard.

Now my question is I have to create the superuser dashboard and admin dashboard components and these dashboards are having the same data as previous user dashboard and some extra user information on it.(From the user login,superuserlogin,admin login It has to navigate to particular dashboard page)

**can any anyone help me is it necessary to create the two more components for superuser dashboard,admin dashboard and copy paste the userdashboard component data in superuser and admin dashboard components.**

I am new to this angular application can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: I suppose you can has a "superdasboard", that has as children your dashboard. The "superdasboard" take account when the use logged is a superuser and when is an admin

Comment: Can you explain brief about it .I did not understand that what you are explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this problem but what I would do is to:

- Break down the dashboard component to even smaller components so you can reuse them later on each of the dashboards thus avoiding copy paste of the template
- Inherit from the base Dashboard class on every other dashboard class so you share common functionality
- Use an Angular service to hold the data that is common to every dashboard and inject it to your dashboard components.
- Create the services for the super user dashboard and the admin dashboard for the extra data that you need to display on those components

Services are basically a class that angular can inject to your components at runtime and usually are use to store data shared among many components
more about [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: Thanks@Shulkmaster .Breakdown of dashboard components to smaller components means within the dashboard component I have to create the another component named superuser dashboard right??

Comment: No. I don't know how you dashboard looks like but let imagine you have a basic dashboard with a picture of the user , a menu with 4 actions, a graph showing some data and a list o items so break down of the component means instead of having a huge component with lots of HTML and typescript you instead create 4 component one for showing the user info with its on logic, one for the graphics with it own login into another angular component, one for the list and so on and all of them share the data from the service.

Comment: So to summarise the dashboard component now is not a single huge component but rather a component make out of 4 components and in the same way you can reuse those 4 component to build the other daahboards, this gives you the flexibility to for instance show the component that diplays the list in the basic daahboar and the super dashboard but not in the admin one. Hope this time I made it cleared for you

Comment: I have created dashboard in that placed the navbar on top side after that placed the google map on left side and in right side placed the data coming from the backend.Now I have to add two more dashboards(super user,admin) having the same data as user dashboard and add one more extra table on it.So can you help me how can I place two more components and add data instead of copy and pasteall tha data from the user dashboard.

Comment: So based on you description you could create 3 smaller components out of your base dashboard, the map,the  navbar and the data from backend so your base dashboard template would look like this:
`<app-navbar><app-navber/>
<app-map></app-map><app-data></app-data>
and now you can reuse those component in you super dashboard in the same way
   <app-navbar><app-navber/>
   <app-map></app-map>
   <app-data></app-data>
  <app-extra-table></app-extra-table>
of course adding the extra thing you need and sharing the data across components using the service

Comment: Thank you very much,So Now I have to create the two components inside the dashboard   and I have to import that dashboard component in superuser component and in superuser.component.html   I have to place  <app-navbar><app-navber/> <app-map></app-map> <app-data></app-data> <app-extra-table></app-extra-table> .So I get all the data  in superuser dashbord ,admin as it is as the dashboard have right? Can you please tell me am I right?

Comment: Yes I thing you got it this time.

Answer (score 1):

Below process will work but may take you abit of coding

- Create or update your `AuthenicationService` by adding a function `can()`
- When a user logs in ensure their information and role &/OR permissions are saved in the service, something like in the interface

```
interface IUser {
  id: number,
  role: string,
  permissions: string[],
  // Other Properties here
}
```

- Update the can function to something like below

```
  can(permission: string) {
    if(this.user.role === 'super admin') return true;
    if(this.user.permissions.includes(permission) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

We are allowing a super admin all access, but for other users we are checking if they have permission to  perform something

- Inject the Authentication service to the dashboard component and set properties for sections you need restricted eg lets say the super admin can block a user we can have something like

```
  constructor (private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, ...) {}
  canBlocUser = this.authenticationService.can('block user')
```

- Finally in your UI you can simply show or hide components based on the property value

```
  <button *ngIf='canBlockUser'>Block User</button>
```